# Captalize letter in a string in order and create an array to store

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
// Create a function that takes a string and turns it into a Mexican Wave.
var smallarr=[]
var   bigarr=[]
var   another=""

function wave(str){
    for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        smallarr.push(str)
    }
    for (var j=0;j<smallarr.length;j++)
    {
        if(smallarr[j][j].toUpperCase()==smallarr[j][j])
        { 
            var c=smallarr[j][j].toLowerCase()
            smallarr[j][j]=c
        }
        else {
            var c=smallarr[j][j].toUpperCase()
            smallarr[j][j]=c}
        }        
    }
    return smallarr     
}

document.write(wave("edabit"))
//console.log(smallarr)
```

The output I expect is wave("edabit") ➞ ["Edabit", "eDabit", "edAbit", "edaBit", "edabIt", "edabiT"] but now the output is the same as the input.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What's the idea behind `if(smallarr[j][j].toUpperCase()==smallarr[j][j]` ?

Comment: You should really put some effort in properly indenting your code.

Comment: @Groo I just want to check if smallarr[j][j] is capitalized or not. : )

Comment: @trincot I don't know... I have tried the automatic formatting on glitch, maybe it's not working perfectly

Comment: You should just paste the code as you have it, select it, and click the `<>` button on the editor. Then it will be as you have it. I hope you did the effort on your side to have it properly indented. Please correct it.

Comment: I have updated your question with better indentation. I hope it is OK for you.

Comment: @trincot oh sure, you can edit it whatever the way you want. I don't know the standard of formatting for code tbh and I don't have an editor on my computer

Comment: Oh but I did not use an editor, I just typed the spaces ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that you try to update a character in a string, but that is not possible. In JavaScript strings are immutable. Trying to assign to a certain index will have no effect to the string.

Instead you must rebuild a string where that one character is different. You can use `slice` to take parts of the string to help you build it.

Here is your code adapted to that effect:

```js
function wave(str) {
    var smallarr = []; // define as local
    for (var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
        let c = str[j]; // Use a variable to avoid duplicate code
        if (c.toUpperCase() === c) {
            c = c.toLowerCase();
        } else {
            c = c.toUpperCase();
        }
        // You cannot modify a string; you need to regenerate one
        smallarr.push(str.slice(0, j) + c + str.slice(j+1));
    }
    return smallarr     
}

console.log(wave("edabit"))
```

Comment: Hi I have a question here:  c = c.toLowerCase()  so I can update one single character. but not a character in a string? but isn't one single character also considered a string?

Comment: Just an update to make sure you see my edit on my previous comment~

Comment: That is not really *mutating* a string. Mutating would be (if it were possible) expressed as `c[0] = c.toLowerCase()`. But when you do `c = c.toLowerCase()`, you actually create a new string and just happen to use the same variable to store that string (thereby losing the previous string that was stored there). That is not mutation, but reassignment. So variables can be reassigned, but strings cannot be mutated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try double [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) where second callback argument represents an index:

```js
let input = "edabit";

let result = input.split('').map(
     (_, i) => input.split('').map(
          (char, j) => i === j ? char.toUpperCase() : char).join()
 );

console.log(result);
```

EDIT:

The problem with your approach is that strings are immutable so you need to build a new string using `slice` like below:

```js
var smallarr=[]
   var   bigarr=[]
   var   another=""
   function wave(str){
    for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
         smallarr.push(str)
      }

     for (var j=0;j<smallarr.length;j++){
       smallarr[j] = smallarr[j].slice(0,j) + smallarr[j][j].toUpperCase() + smallarr[j].slice(j+1);
     }
   return smallarr     
   }

  document.write(wave("edabit"))
  console.log(smallarr)
```

or just using one loop:

```js
   function wave(str){
    var smallarr=[]
    for (var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
         smallarr.push(str.slice(0,i) + str[i].toUpperCase() + str.slice(i+1))
      }
     return smallarr     
   }
  console.log(wave("edabit"))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, this looks nice. but is it possible for you to have a solution based on my code? I only learnt very basic methods so far...

Comment: Not down-voting, but I avoid doubling any of the functional Javascript array functions if I can avoid it, it amounts to looping twice over the same data, I have always been successful in converting such multiple loops using reduce.

Comment: @JiangYuxin Please go find some online documentation and tutorials then, you should be able to find them by googlin, StackOverflow doesn't exist to help you learn the basics of coding or a particular language, sorry

Comment: @JiangYuxin added loop-based version

Answer (score 2):

You can split the input string into an array of characters and then map over it replacing the current character with it's uppercase version:

```js
const wave = (str) => {
  return str
    .split('')
    .map((char, index) =>
      str.substr(0, index) + char.toUpperCase() + str.substr(index + 1))
}

console.log(wave('edabit'));
```

Comment: but why return at the beginning, doesn't it stop the function from executing?

Comment: `return` at the beginning just means the we return the result of the very first expression inside the function body. And the first expression includes all the operations such as `split` and `map` methods that are needed to produce the result

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#:~:targetText=Array.,such%20as%20Map%20and%20Set%20).) to create an array from the string. In the callback (`mapFn`) get the current letter, and the current index, use them with [`String.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to build a new string with the uppercased letter.

```js
const fn = str => Array.from(str, (c, i) =>
  str.substring(0, i) + c.toUpperCase() + str.substring(i + 1)
);

const result = fn('edabit');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string, map the array and take the splittes string for another mapping by checking the index and use an upper case letter for matching indices.

```js
const
    wave = (string) => string
        .split('')
        .map((_, i, splitted) => splitted.map((c, j) => i === j ? c.toUpperCase() : c).join(''));
    };

console.log(wave('edabit'));
```

A classic approach

```js
function wave(string) {
    var result = [],
        i, j, temp;

    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        temp = '';
        for (j = 0; j < string.length; j++) {
            temp += i === j ? string[j].toUpperCase() : string[j];
        }
        result.push(temp);
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(wave('edabit'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, char) {
    var a = this.split("");
    a[index] = char;
    return a.join("");
}

const createEdibet = ( word ) => {
  console.log('word ' + word.split(''));
  let array = word.split('')
  array.map((letter, i) => {
      let a = word.replaceAt(i, letter.toUpperCase());
      console.log(a);
      return a;
    });
    console.log(array)
    
   // console.log(words)
}

createEdibet('edabit');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array length is small you can use `split`, `map`, `join` like this:

```js
let text = `edabit`;

let results = text.split('').map((char,index,original)=>{
  let temp = [...original];
  temp[index]=temp[index].toUpperCase();
  return temp.join('');
});

console.log(results);
```

But in big array it's not optimized.